# Change method in other project

Tags: c#

I'm working in a C# application.

I have a library used to generate matrix. For the debug I created a method `WriteToFile`. But this library is used for an application on PC and an other one on android (maybe iOS later). So I don't want to use IO in this library.

There is my solution :

- `ProjectLibrary`
- `ProjectPC`
- `ProjectAndroid`

Actually there is a class in ProjectLibrary for the matrix

```
namespace ProjectLibrary
{
    public class Matrix
    {
        public void Generate()
        {
            //Generate Step 1

            //for the debug I want to use this method sometime
            WriteToFile();

            //Generate Step 2
        }

        public void WriteToFile()
        {
            //TODO
            //if ProjectPC write on PC
            //if ProjectAndroid write on phone
        }
    }
}
```

My question is : How can I create the method `WriteToFile` ? This method have to be called in my project `ProjectLibrary` but depending on `ProjectPC` and `ProjectAndroid` it will not be the same.

Comment: You can have it written in the individual versions (`ProjectPC` and `ProjectAndroid`) as an override method

Comment: Is is possible to declare an override method in a class without create a new class inherited ?

Comment: Have a look at the [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)

Comment: This is the whole purpose of interfaces. Let all your three classes implement a common interface with a `WriteToFile`-method.

Comment: I guess you can pass a parameter that will contain some value that will mean PC or Android and apply if else like **if PC** then do this else **do something else**

Comment: IoC containers + strategy pattern will be a good solution here. In your code you will use just interface methods, and IoC will decide what metod to use depends on the project name

Comment: Strategy pattern looks good, I'll to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an interface and depedency injection !

In your project library create the interface:

```
public interface IFileWriter
{
    void WriteToFile();
}
```

Then modify your Matrix class to add the dependency :

```
public class Matrix
    {
        private IFileWriter _writer;

        public Matrix(IFileWriter writer)
        {
             _writer = writer;
        }

        public void Generate()
        {
            //Generate Step 1

            //for the debug I want to use this method sometime
            _writer.WriteToFile();

            //Generate Step 2
        }


    }
```

In your Windows project then you create a Class inheriting from IFileWriter :

```
public class WindowsFileWriter : IFileWriter
{
    public void WriteToFile()
    {
        //Your windows code
    }
}
```

Then you do the same in your Android Project :

```
public class AndroidFileWriter : IFileWriter
{
    public void WriteToFile()
    {
        //Your android  code
    }
}
```

And then when you need your matrix class in Android you just have to call it this way :

```
AndroidFileWriter myAndroidFileWriter = new AndroidFileWriter();
Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix(myAndroidFileWriter );
myMatrix.Generate();
```

And in Windows :

```
WindowsFileWriter myWindowsFileWriter = new WindowsFileWriter();
Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix(myWindowsFileWriter );
myMatrix.Generate();
```

Even better (from my point of view) if you use some Mvvm framework you can register in the IOC your implementation of IFileWriter !

For example with MvvmCross this would give you :

```
Mvx.Register<IFileWriter, AndroidFileWriter>(); //in your android project start
```

and

```
Mvx.Register<IFileWriter, WindowsFileWriter>(); //in your windows project start
```

And then calling :

```
Mvx.Resolve<IFileWriter>().Generate();
```

in your core project